# returning a value from ajax modal dialog to main view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using jQuery to open a modal dialog like this:

```
$('#AddCustomerDialog').dialog(
    {
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 400,
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons:
    {
        "Done": function () {
        $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});


$('#AddCustomerLink').click(function () {
    linkObj = $(this);
    var dialogDiv = $('#AddCustomerDialog');
    var viewUrl = "/Cases/AddCustomer";
    $.get(viewUrl, function(data) {
        dialogDiv.html(data);
        //open dialog
        dialogDiv.dialog('open');
    });
    return false;
    });
});
```

The purpose of the partial view on the dialog is to enter a new customer record "on the fly". I would like to have the new customer id returned to the calling view but I am not sure how to do that with the code I am using. Any suggestions or examples would be appreciated.

****EDIT 08/16/2012*****

So should I do something like this with the controller action?

```
public JsonResult AddCustomer()
{
    var result = ...insert statement here

    ...linq select to get new customerid
    {
       CustomerID = c.CustomerID
       ...
    };
return Json(variable, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

I know that is messy but with that basic idea will that give me what I need?

R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for the "Done" button click callback something like

```
if (!$("#AddCustomerDialog form").valid())
    return false;
var postUrl = $("#AddCustomerDialog form").attr('action');
$.post(postUrl, $(containerSelector + ' form').serialize(),
        function (result) {
            $("#AddCustomerDialog").dialog("close");
            var addedCustomerId = result.Id;
        });
```

Also AddCustomer action (for post request) should return added customer in Json format.

Comment: Hi Denis 
I added some code to my question based on your suggestion for the controller returning json. Do I have the basic idea right?

Answer (score 0):

declare a variable in your html page script, now in the return data from your php code add an echo script with  the variable name and set here the id you want

in your script: var foo;

in your php code

```
echo 'data for insert in div';
echo '<script>foo=id_you_want</script>';
exit();
```

with this you set the foo var in the html page with the id of the new customer and can use it

Comment: Hi Alex, I am using ASP.NET MVC not PHP.